# How To ignore Endpoints from openapi.yaml in generation with openapi-generator-maven-plugin/

Tags: spring-boot, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

yaml and openapi-generator-maven-plugin is corretly generating Spring Boot Controller Interfaces from it. All is working fine. But now we want to overwrite one of the generated Interfaces with our own interface. How can we exclude a certain endpoint from this generation?

Example:

```
  paths:
  /currencies:
    get:
      tags:
        - DomainData
      summary: Lists all valid currencies available.
      operationId: "getCurrencies"
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/AcceptLanguage'
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "OK"
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: string
                additionalProperties:
                  type: string
        '401':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/Unauthorized'
        '5XX':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/Unexpected'

  /languages:
    get:
      tags:
        - DomainData
      summary: Lists all valid languages available.
      operationId: "getLanguages"
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/AcceptLanguage'
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "OK"
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: string
                additionalProperties:
                  type: string
        '401':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/Unauthorized'
        '5XX':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/Unexpected'
```

This is a part of the openapi.yaml and we would not like to generate for /languages but everything else.

Comment: Can't you remove it from open-api specs?

Comment: @ShivajiPote no we generate the swagger from it and would like to keep it there.

Comment: But will that swagger be useful if there is no API implementation?

Comment: Yes it is very useful. The problem is that the gateway take that endpoint from another server but it should be seen in swagger. cause its looks for the API user as it is one api.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution we used a .openapi-generator-ignore
and linked it in the pom options of the openapi generator.

In the .openapi-generator-ignore we used the full relative path from position of the ignore file to the file that is not existing and we dont want to get generated.

target/generated-sources/v1/src/main/java/ch/company/dsp/bff/project/generated/api/languageApi.java